# user defined illegal exception

Tags: c#, exception, defined

I have this program where I'm supposed to return illegal triangle exception if sum of any 2 sides are greater than one. Where am i supposed to put the

```
if(side1 + side2 < side3)
    throw new illegalTriangleException("Sum of any 2 sides not bigger than the other side");
if(side1 + side3 < side2)
    throw new illegalTriangleException("Sum of any 2 sides not bigger than the other side");
if(side3 + side2 < side1)
    throw new illegalTriangleException("Sum of any 2 sides not bigger than the other side");
```

in here? I'm not sure where to put it. Also i would like to know if my way of writing the code is correct?

```
class Triangle
{
    public double side1, side2, side3;
    public Triangle() { }
    public Triangle(double s1, double s2, double s3)
    {
        side1 = s1;
        side2 = s2;
        side3 = s3;
    }
    public double Side1
    {
        get { return side1; }
        set {
            if (value<0)
            side1 = value;
        }
    }
    public double Side2
    {
        get { return side2; }
        set {
            if (value < 0)
            side2 = value;
        }
    }
    public double Side3
    {
        get { return side3; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0)
            side3 = value;
        }
    }
}

class IllegalTriangleException : Exception
{
    public IllegalTriangleException() : base ("Sum of any 2 sides is not greater than the other") { }
    public IllegalTriangleException(string msg) : base("Sum of any 2 sides is not greater than the other" + msg) { }
    public IllegalTriangleException(string msg, Exception innerException) : base("Sum of any 2 sides is not greater than the other" + msg, innerException){ }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Length of side: ");
            double side1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            double side2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            double side3 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Your triangle is puuuuurfect");
        }
        catch (IllegalTriangleException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Arguably your condition should be `<=`, depending on whether you consider the "triangle" `Triangle(1, 1, 2)` to be a degenerate line

Comment: What purpose does `if (value < 0)` serve here? Should that not be `>`?

Comment: Also, you never actually instantiate `Triangle` in your code

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all.

- Properties are public and internal fields should be private. Read this guide https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- You should first make an instance of your Triangle with the  Triangle(double s1, double s2, double s3) constructor. In that constructor you can call the private CheckForIllegalTriangle() to check the side lengths. This will then throw your exception if there is a fault.
- Make the default constructor private. So you dont have to worrie about calling the CheckForIllegalTriangle().

```
class Triangle
{
    private double side1, side2, side3;

    private Triangle() { }

    public Triangle(double s1, double s2, double s3)
    {
        side1 = s1;
        side2 = s2;
        side3 = s3;

        CheckForIllegalTriangle();
    }

    public double Side1
    {
        get { return side1; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0)
                side1 = value;
        }
    }

    public double Side2
    {
        get { return side2; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0)
                side2 = value;
        }
    }

    public double Side3
    {
        get { return side3; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0)
                side3 = value;
        }
    }

    public void CheckForIllegalTriangle()
    {
        if ((side1 + side2 < side3) ||
           (side1 + side3 < side2) ||
           (side3 + side2 < side1))
            throw new IllegalTriangleException("Sum of any 2 sides not bigger than the other side");
    }
}


class IllegalTriangleException : Exception
{
    public IllegalTriangleException() : base("Sum of any 2 sides is not greater than the other") { }
    public IllegalTriangleException(string msg) : base("Sum of any 2 sides is not greater than the other" + msg) { }
    public IllegalTriangleException(string msg, Exception innerException) : base("Sum of any 2 sides is not greater than the other" + msg, innerException) { }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Length of side 1: ");
            double side1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Length of side 2: ");
            double side2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Length of side 3: ");
            double side3 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Triangle t1 = new Triangle(side1, side2, side3);

            Console.WriteLine("Your triangle is puuuuurfect");
        }
        catch (IllegalTriangleException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Zohar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30442501/102441) is a good implementation of a mutable triangle with invariants.

However, there's a good argument for immutability here (ie, no setters), otherwise you end up with issues passing through invalid states to transition between valid ones:

```
Triangle a(3, 4, 5);
Triangle b(30, 40, 50);

// let's adjust triangle a to match b
try {
    a.Side1 = b.Side1;  // nope
    a.Side2 = b.Side2;
    a.Side3 = b.Side3;
}
catch(IllegalTriangleException e) {
    // darn, we accidentally went through an invalid state of (30, 4, 5)
}
```

The immutable version is much simpler to implement

```
class ImmutableTriangle
{
    public ImmutableTriangle(double side1, double side2, double side3)
    {
        if(side1 + side2 <= side3 ||
           side2 + side3 <= side1 ||
           side3 + side1 <= side2)
            throw new IllegalTriangleException("Sum of any 2 sides not bigger than the other side");
        }
        if(side1 <= 0 || side2 <= 0 || side3 <= 0)
            throw new IllegalTriangleException("Sides must be positive");
        }
        Side1 = side1;
        Side2 = side2;
        Side3 = side3;
    }
    public double Side1 { get; private set; }
    public double Side2 { get; private set; }
    public double Side3 { get; private set; }
}
```

(Note I've also swapped `<` for `<=`, and fixed the negative lengths checks)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do:
By keeping the fields private you ensure that any value assignment to them will be only by using the appropriate properties.
Note that the constructor is assigning the first and second values to the fields and the third to the property to check for illegal triangles.

```
public class Triangle
{
    private double _side1, _side2, _side3;
    public Triangle() { }
    public Triangle(double side1, double side2, double side3)
    {
        _side1 = side1;
        _side2 = side2;
        Side3 = side3; // Note: this is calling the property
    }
    public double Side1
    {
        get { return _side1; }
        set {
            if (value > 0) 
            {
            CheckForIllegalTriangle(value, Side2, Side3);
            _side1 = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public double Side2
    {
        get { return _side2; }
        set {
            if (value > 0)
            {
            CheckForIllegalTriangle(Side1, value, Side3);
            _side2 = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public double Side3
    {
        get { return _side3; }
        set
        {
            if (value > 0)
            {
            CheckForIllegalTriangle(Side1, Side2, value);
            _side3 = value;
            }
        }
    }

    private void CheckForIllegalTriangle(double side1, double side2, double side3) {
        if((side1 + side2 < side3) || 
           (side1 + side3 < side2) || 
           (side3 + side2 < side1))
        {
           throw new illegalTriangleException("Sum of any 2 sides not bigger than the other side");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `CheckForIllegalTriangle()` won't work, because you don't use the new value when checking

Comment: "`&& CheckForIllegalTriangle()`" - You can't use a void return value in a boolean expression

Comment: This will fail when assigning side 2, since at that point the triangle will be invalid. You need to initialize the first two sides with fields

Comment: This is what you get when writing code after 30 hours without sleep... will try to fix it...

Comment: Also add a test in the constructor for values that must be bigger then 0.

Comment: Now your braces don't match. But you're getting there!

Comment: @Eric thanks for picking up on my mistakes. Now after I've got some sleep I think I've managed to get it right...

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible that every side is greater than the 2 others, so I think your question is wrong. But here is what I think you're trying to achieve.

```
 class Triangle
    {
        public double side1, side2, side3;
        public Triangle() { }
        public Triangle(double s1, double s2, double s3)
        {
            side1 = s1;
            side2 = s2;
            side3 = s3;
            if(side1 + side2 < side3)
               throw new illegalTriangleException("Sum of any 2 sides not bigger than the other side");
            if(side1 + side3 < side2)
               throw new illegalTriangleException("Sum of any 2 sides not bigger than the other side");
            if(side3 + side2 < side1)
               throw new illegalTriangleException("Sum of any 2 sides not bigger than the other side");
        }
        public double Side1
        {
            get { return side1; }
            set {
                if (value>0)
                side1 = value;
            }
        }
        public double Side2
        {
            get { return side2; }
            set {
                if (value > 0)
                side2 = value;
            }
        }
        public double Side3
        {
            get { return side3; }
            set
            {
                if (value > 0)
                side3 = value;
            }
        }
    }

    class IllegalTriangleException : Exception
    {
        public IllegalTriangleException(string msg) : base(msg) { }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Length of side: ");
                double side1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                double side2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                double side3 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Triangle t = new Triangle(side1, side2, side3);
                Console.WriteLine("Your triangle is puuuuurfect");
            }
            catch (IllegalTriangleException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: _"It's impossible that every side is greater than the [sum of] 2 others"_ - can you produce a counter example?

Comment: sure. a triangle with side 3cm 2cm 1cm. 3+2 =5. 1cm is not greater than 5cm so the side 1cm is not greater than the sum of 2 others

Comment: Just realized that I've read that wrong, and so have you. The requirement is that **no** side is greater than the sum of two others. Also, I'd argue that `(1, 2, 3)` does not describe a triangle, as it is degenerate

Comment: I read it correctly "if sum of any 2 sides are greater than one" . It's |OP that worded it badly. If you read my code it's exactly what I did.

Comment: hahaha yes you're right my example is not possible but even if I change the value it's right